# Is there a builtin way to flip the i-th dimension of an nd-array?

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array

Basically, I'm looking for a generalization of `flipud` and `fliplr` to flip the i-th dimension of an nd-array.

When the dimension to be flipped is the first one, I guess I can use

```
function flipped = flipfirst(ndarr)
    sz = size(ndarr);
    flipped = reshape(flipud(reshape(ndarr, sz(1), [])), sz);
end
```

Likewise, if the dimension to be flipped is the last one, I could use

```
function flipped = fliplast(ndarr)
    sz = size(ndarr);
    flipped = reshape(fliplr(reshape(ndarr, [], sz(end))), sz);
end
```

I'm sure that I can code something more general, with calls to `permute` and whatnot, but is there anything built-in for this?

I'm not sure how expensive it is to do all the `reshape`-ing above, but if it is, I'd also be interested in more efficient non-built-in approaches.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have R2013b+ you should use the [new](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btz131f-1) [`flip`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flip.html) function:

```
A = rand(2,2,2);
B = flip(A,3);
```

For older versions you can use [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html):

```
A = rand(2,2,2);
B = flipdim(A,3);
```

Type `edit flipdim` in your command window to see the clever code for `flipdim`.

Comment: Good links.  I wonder how `flip` "provides a faster and more memory efficient alternative" and how significant of an improvement it gives. In any case, I'll be sure to "flip" from `flipdim` to `flip`.

Comment: @chappjc: `flip` is a native function whereas `flipdim` is not. Is some simple timing tests `flip` is about 2.5 times faster for large arrays on my machine. In the case of large arrays at least, `flipdim` needs to build a big index vector, but there are likely other C-level optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

You can also flip an array by using the [time reversal property of the Discrete Fourier Transform](http://www.claysturner.com/dsp/timereversal.pdf). The code below works for any number of dimensions, but we demonstrate it with a 2D array because it's easier to examine the results.

```matlab
A = magic(8);

d = 1; % dimension along which to flip

% Create frequency array w, we need it to go along dimension d
sz = size(A, d);
w = 2*pi * (0:sz-1) / sz;
w = shiftdim(w(:), 1-d);

% The actual time reversal property:
B = ifft( conj(fft(A, [], d)) .* exp(1j*w), [], d, 'symmetric');
```

<sub>(yes, this is overly complicated and ridiculously expensive compared to `flip`, but it's fun!)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

From [`flipdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipdim.html):

> Flip array along specified dimension

Answer (score 2):

Mostly for fun too...

This uses a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) generated from a cell array, together with the not very well known fact that [you can use `':'` as an index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22539481/2586922):

```
A = rand(3,4,5);                  % input array
dim = 2;                          % dimension to flip along
c = repmat({':'}, 1, ndims(A));
c{dim} = size(A, dim):-1:1;
B = A(c{:});
```

Comment: It turns out that this is very similar to how `flipdim` is coded, as noted by @CrisLuengo